# Snakemake rule higher priority than all other rules

Tags: python, python-3.x, snakemake, directed-acyclic-graphs

So I know that in order to set rule priority, you use `ruleorder`. Is there an efficient way to give a rule priority over all other rules? For example, suppose I have rules `a`, `b`, and `c`. I would like rule `b` to have higher priority over `a` and `c`. How would I do this other than manually doing `ruleorder: b > c` and `ruleorder: b > a`?

Comment: Do all the rules have the same, ambigious output files and are all colliding with each other? This seems like a strange situation, usually you should try to avoid ambiguity as much as possible and `ruleorder` shouldn't be needed for more than a pair of rules.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you care about `priority` or `ruleorder`, i.e. scheduling priority or ambiguity handling?

Comment: I care about ruleorder in order to handle ambiguities!

Comment: I don't think there is another solution to this at the moment. Maybe as a side comment you might want to look at your code and workflow again and see if you can get rid of the ambiguities in another way? In my personal opinion `ruleorder` should rarely - if at all - be necessary. Certainly not with 20+ rules as you write in one of the comments below.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to specify rule-specific priority using [`priority` directive](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#priorities):

```py
rule a:
   priority: 100
```

The default priority for a rule is 0, so assigning any value greater than 0 will push the rule above the other rules that are ready for execution. Similarly, one can assign negative priority values, so a rule is executed last relative to other rules that are ready for execution.

The specific numeric value is not important, what is important is the relative ordering of the assigned priorities.

Comment: `priority` and `ruleorder` do not serve the same purpose, while the former is relevant during execution and scheduling, the later is relevant for rule ambiguity handling.

Comment: Thanks, @euronion, that's a valid remark! From the question statement, though, it seems that OP is actually interested in `priority` (rather than ambiguity resolution).

Comment: Maybe OP could clarify? Based on the example `ruleorder: b > c` given I think OP cares about ambiguity handling.

Comment: I'm actually more curious about ambiguity handling (ruleorder). I had no idea about priority!

Answer (score 2):

To resolve ambiguities one can provide all the rule orderings in one statement:

```py
ruleorder: b > a > c
```

Comment: In my case, I would like to have `b` be potentially higher than 20 rules. This solution works, but I'm looking for a better solution where you don't have to write out that `b` is higher than the other 20 rules manually.

Comment: AFAIK what you are looking for is not possible in the current implementation.